# Comparing two lists and sorting added and removed entries

Tags: java, bukkit

I am attempting to compare two lists and have added entries put into one list and removed entries put into another. Here is the current code:

```
        Map<Chunk, List<Player>> chunkListMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (Chunk c : affectedChunks) {
            List<Player> currentPlayers = playersInChunk(c);
            if (!chunkListMap.containsKey(c)) {
                chunkListMap.put(c, currentPlayers);
                continue;
            }
            List<Player> previousPlayers = chunkListMap.get(c);

            List<Player> enteringPlayers = new ArrayList<>(currentPlayers);
            enteringPlayers.removeAll(previousPlayers);
            for (Player player : enteringPlayers) applyEffects(player);

            List<Player> leavingPlayers = new ArrayList<>(previousPlayers);
            leavingPlayers.removeAll(currentPlayers);
            for (Player player : leavingPlayers) unapplyEffects(player);
        }

private List<Player> playersInChunk(Chunk c) {
    List<Player> retVal = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Entity e : c.getEntities()) if (e instanceof Player) retVal.add((Player) e);
    return retVal;
}
```

The two result lists (enteringPlayers and leavingPlayers) are always empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check if you needed `continue` there?

Comment: What is `playersInChunk()` doing? Post the full code.

Comment: @user2004685 Updated the post.

Comment: I tested your code and everything worked (the lists were not empty after I moved into a different chunk), the only thing I would note is that your code only iterates through the `Chunk`s in the `affectedChunks` iterable, not all `Chunk`s in the `chunkListMap`, so if `affectedChunks` does not contain the chunk that the player moved out of/into, the lists will be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While without knowing the business logic or seeing the complete code, it is not going to be easy saying why. But let me think what may be a possible cause:

You will only execute the code  following the for-loop when a Player is already present in chunkListMap. And that chunk c is what you use to retrieve previousPlayers.

```
        List<Player> previousPlayers = chunkListMap.get(c);
```

Now you also extract currentPlayers with

```
        List<Player> currentPlayers = playersInChunk(c);
```

In the event all currentPlayers in the specific Chunk object are of type Player, this will mean currentPlayers and previousPlayers are same.

Then if you do:

```
        enteringPlayers.removeAll(previousPlayers);
```

it removes all entries from this. Hence, you will see null.

The following dirty and rough example will show you that:

```
package collectionuse;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

class Entity{
    String name;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Chunk{
    Entity[] entity;
    String name;

    Chunk(){

    }

    Chunk(String name){
        this.name = name;
        entity = new Entity[2];
        Entity e1 = new Player();
        Entity e2 = new Player();
        e1.setName(name);
        e2.setName("Dummy");
        entity[0] = e1;
        entity[1] = e2;
    }

    public Entity[] getEntities() {
        return entity;
    }
}

class Player extends Entity{

}

public class MapsT {

    public void checkMap(){
        Map<Chunk, List<Player>> chunkListMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Chunk> affectedChunks = new ArrayList<Chunk>();
        Chunk ch = new Chunk("Z");
        affectedChunks.add(0, ch);
        affectedChunks.add(1, ch);

        affectedChunks.add(2, new Chunk("A"));
        affectedChunks.add(3, new Chunk("B"));
        affectedChunks.add(4, new Chunk("C"));
        affectedChunks.add(5, new Chunk("D"));

        for (Chunk c : affectedChunks) {
          List<Player> currentPlayers = playersInChunk(c);
          if (!chunkListMap.containsKey(c)) {
            chunkListMap.put(c, currentPlayers);
            continue;
        }

        List<Player> previousPlayers = chunkListMap.get(c);
        List<Player> enteringPlayers = new ArrayList<>(currentPlayers);
        enteringPlayers.removeAll(previousPlayers);
        //for (Player player : enteringPlayers) applyEffects(player);

        List<Player> leavingPlayers = new ArrayList<>(previousPlayers);
        leavingPlayers.removeAll(currentPlayers);
        //for (Player player : leavingPlayers) unapplyEffects(player);
        }

    }

    private List<Player> playersInChunk(Chunk c) {
        List<Player> retVal = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Entity e : c.getEntities()) {
            if (e instanceof Player) retVal.add((Player) e);
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MapsT mapt = new MapsT();
        mapt.checkMap();
    }

}
```

Comment: Current players and previous players were in fact the same. I decided to go with a totally different approach that checks for when a player moves and then checks if the player is still in the chunk. If not, they've left. Thank you!